# Select2 selected options with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, select, jquery-select2

I'm using Select2 to do some generic filters.
I get options from my server with an Ajax request, now I need to set the selected options with data from a Cookie.

I'm trying with:

```
$("#categoriesselector").select2("val",["01002"]);
$("#categoriesselector").val(["01002"]);
$("#categoriesselector").select2().val(["01002"]);
```

But this not works.
Any idea about what could be happening?
Thanks, Iván.

Comment: How are you initializing Select2 in the first place? That's going determine what the best answer is.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I was initializing with:

$("#caegoriesselector").select2({
    ajax.{......},
    ..........
});


I have already solved, now I'm doing ajax request in an external function and fill Select2 with:

$("#caegoriesselector").select2({
    data:data,
    ..........
});

I think the problem was that Select2 doesn't save result from the Ajax request, so when I was trying to select some value this did not exist.

Answer (score 0):

From [Select2 docs](https://select2.github.io/options.html#data) you have to set `data` when calling select2, like so:

```
$('#categoriesselector').select2({
  data: [
    {
      id: '01002',
      text: '01002'
    }
  ]
});
```

Comment: I have 100 of select2 on my page, I  think to set something direct in my html mockup. what could be the best, with ajax feature. currently I use selected attribute.

Answer (score 0):

To display the selected options on your select2 you have to run the following line:

```
$('#id_of_your_select2').val(array_of_selection_ids).trigger('change')
```